# Logitech Illumination SDK Pulse Effect Not Returning to G600

Tags: c#, rgb, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I am using the Logitech Illumination SDK and having trouble with the pulse effect, allow me to explain.

Here is my code

```
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            LogitechGSDK.LogiLedInit();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            LogitechGSDK.LogiLedSaveCurrentLighting();
           
            LogitechGSDK.LogiLedPulseLighting(50,0,50,LogitechGSDK.LOGI_LED_DURATION_INFINITE,250);
            Console.ReadLine();
            LogitechGSDK.LogiLedRestoreLighting();
            LogitechGSDK.LogiLedShutdown();
            

        }
```

So in expectation, this code will print out hello world, initialize the SDK, save the current lighting make it pulse purple until a character is inputted. After the input, it should restore the lighting and then exit the app.

So it almost works. On Logitech Gaming Software I have the pulse effect selected and am using the onboard profiles. When the lighting is restored, instead of restoring the pulse effect, it goes to a solid color. The color is right but it SHOULD BE BLINKING and its not. So this has annoyed me to the max and now I will go and show you guys what I tried.

I have tried to remove the Shutdown line. No dice.
I have tried to remove the LogiLedSave/Restores. No dice.
I have tried combining both the above. No dice.

I have also tried the above 3 with a solid color effect. Same result.

Same result.
every time.
I understand this SDK is written extremely badly but I think there must be something I can do. Appreciate any help on this problem.

The mouse does the correct effect and then fails.

Thanks

EDIT: The pulse effect I am talking about is not the pulse effect in code, but rather the one I set up in Logitech Gaming Software.

Answer (score 0):

`LogiLedPulseLighting` is not a hardware backed method. It means the effect you see if being run by your computer rather than the KeyBoard hardware.

Due to this reason your application must keep running as long as you need that Pulse effect running. Unfortunately there is no extensive documentation available but with experience I came to this information.

If you wish to verify my claim then just add a breakpoint after `Console.ReadLine();` and you will see that the Pulse effect stops the moment you break into the code because debugger also pauses all worker threads.

In case you keep running your application in background (service or system tray) make sure not to call `LogiLedShutdown()` until you are done with it and want to disconnect from the device.

Comment: So the effect I am talking about is after the end of the program. The problem is when the program closes the effect is not pulsing even thought logitech gaming software is set to make it pulse. Like the code makes it blinkpurple but before the code runs it blinks red. After the code runs it is a solid red and I have to cycle through profiles again to get the RGB blink  to work.

Comment: https://support.logi.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360025298053-Logitech-Gaming-Software, this is the logitech gaming software I am talking about. GHUB is broken software. But if I quit logitech gaming software, the program does not do anything. Is there a HW method to tell the mouse to switch onboard profiles?

Comment: Sorry I have limited experience with Logitech programming (personal use). After your comment I tried to run my code without GHub and it failed to initialize. But with GHub running in background it works fine and I am able to make it `LogiLedPulseLighting ` whenever needed.